# BunJs CLI scripting in Yaml

Tags: javascript, yaml, command-line-interface, package.json, bun

Is there a bun.js CLI tool that can read scripts written in Yaml?

For example, in node.js, package.json is processed by npm, and script can be defined and run from the CLI, but json is not an easy-to-read format. In Deno, there is a specific tool (still in development) called Velociraptor (`vr`) that replace npm for scripts execution.

Comment: You can dump any yaml file as json. A very simple python script can do that, you have cli tools available, I'm even que sure js has libs to acheive this.

Comment: thanks Zeitounator. This can be accepted as a work-around, but my question is about a native use of Yaml (see Deno's Velociraptor [here](https://velociraptor.run))